# C++ Member Variable value changes based on whether or not it is printed out

Tags: c++

I have a class `ZoneDeVie` containing a vector of vectors of `Bacterie*`. The `Bacterie` class contains an int value `energie` (set to 10 by default) and a `toString()` function which prints the value. In the `ZoneDeVie` constructor, I build the 2D table, populating each cell with a default instance of a `Bacterie`. Then, in my main method, I'm testing by printing the `toString()` of the last `Bacterie` in the table. For some reason, it returns a random, obnoxiously-large int (usually something like: 3753512); however, if I make a call to the Bacterie's `toString()` method in the constructor of ZoneDeVie, the main method will print out correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Bacterie {
public:
    Bacterie() { this->energie = 10; }
    string toString() {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << "Energie: " << this->energie;
        return ss.str();
    }
protected:
    int energie;
};

class ZoneDeVie {
public:
    ZoneDeVie(int width, int height) {
        Bacterie* bac = new Bacterie();

        // without this [following] line, the call to `toString`
        // in the main method will return an obnoxiously-large value
        //bac->toString();
        for (int i=0; i<height; i++) {
            vector<Bacterie*> bacvec = vector<Bacterie*>();
            this->tableau.push_back(bacvec);
            for (int j=0; j<width; j++) {
                this->tableau[i].push_back(bac);
            }
        }
    }
    vector<vector<Bacterie*> > tableau;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int x,y;
    x = 9; y = 39;
    ZoneDeVie zdv = ZoneDeVie(10,40);
    cout << "zdv(" << x << "," << y << ") = " << zdv.tableau[x][y]->toString();

    return 0;
}
```

**output (with a call to "toString()" in ZoneDeVie's constructor):** `zdv(9,39) = Energie: 10`

**output (w/o a call to "toString()" in ZoneDeVie's constructor):** `zdv(9,39) = Energie: 4990504`

Why in the world do I need to call my toString() method before calling it in the main method in order for it to behave as expected?

Comment: Have you defined the destructor `ZoneDeVie::~ZoneDeVie`?

Comment: You must have some undefined behaviour for writing or reading beyond the bounds of an array, or accessing some part of memory you shouldn't, or some uninitialized primitive type or pointer somewhere.

Comment: Any reason for all the pointers?

Comment: Do you intentionally put 400 times same pointer to your vectors?

Comment: @fontanini: I suppose it is technically defined, but empty (`{}`), and removing it changes nothing.
@juanchopanza: You can check the code, I don't believe '9' or '39' should be beyond the values of the array. I can post the code for the `operator()` if you think that would help
@chris: At some point, those pointers will point to different instances. Moreover, the homework assignment specifies a table of pointers. No idea why as I'm a C++ noob.
@TadeuszKopec: Yes.

Comment: Okay, we can't guess. Post a SSCCE: http://sscce.org/

Comment: As @fontanini says, reduce your example. It can be about 20 lines. Get rid of everything that doesn't cause the problem.

Comment: @fontanini I updated the question with an SSCCE. You should be able to copy/paste/compile

Comment: @PeterWood Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with C++ to know how to cleanly reduce the above code to 20 lines. Additionally, I don't know more specifically what is causing the problem so I've included anything I think might be helpful to know.

Comment: @weberc2 Okay, editted my answer. This fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The end condition in your for loops are swapped. You should first iterate through `width` and then through `height`:

```
class ZoneDeVie {
public:
    ZoneDeVie(int width, int height) {
        Bacterie* bac = new Bacterie();

        for (int i=0; i<width; i++) {
            vector<Bacterie*> bacvec = vector<Bacterie*>();
            this->tableau.push_back(bacvec);
            for (int j=0; j<height; j++) {
                this->tableau[i].push_back(bac);
            }
        }
    }
    vector<vector<Bacterie*> > tableau;
};
```

This compiles and provides the correct output.

Comment: Although the formal semantics do require copy construction here, the standard explicitly allows it to be elided, and I don't know of a compiler which doesn't elide it.

Comment: I defined ZoneDeVie::~ZoneDeVie, but it does nothing (`{}`)... Anyway, could you be more explicit with respect to explaining why calling toString() in the ZoneDeVie constructor has any bearing on what happens in the main method?

Comment: Additionally, removing ZoneDeVie::~ZoneDeVie doesn't affect the outcome at all.

Comment: Thank you very much. Even with the loops reversed, could you explain why the "bac->toString();" line affected the outcome?

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, I'd like to +1 your answer; however, someone downvoted my question putting me below the minimum rep to upvote. Sorry :(

Comment: You were accessing invalid memory. That is undefined behavior. Undefined behavior means "anything can happen". That "anything" can be "calling bac->toString() makes my code work". You never know what can happen when you trigger undefined behavior.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with this code.

1. It's not clear what the default constructor of `Bacterie` does.
2. It's not clear what `ZoneDeVie::tableau` is and how the local vector `bacvec` is used.
3. It's not clear how the copy constructor and `operator=` for class `ZoneDeVie` are defined (both are used in `main()`).
4. It seems that all entries in your table are initialised with a pointer to the same `Bacterie` `bac`

Comment: 1) `Bacterie::Bacterie() {this->energie = 10;}`
2) ZoneDeVie::tableau is the vector of vectors, as previously stated. `bacvec` is a row in the table being used to populate the table in the ZoneDeVie constructor.
3) `operator=` is not overridden and ZoneDeVie is not a derived class
4) That is correct

Comment: @weberc2: That should be part of the question, not a comment.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas that information was already available or derivable based on the contents of the question. It seems silly to reiterate it. In the event I was being unclear, I've edited my answer to include a compilable example.

Comment: @weberc2: I am not sure if you are aware that if the obvious was true, there would be no question. When asking for help, make sure to help others in helping you. Trying to guess what may be wrong in your code based on assumptions makes no sense.

Comment: I made no assumptions. I offered all relevant parts of my code and addressed each of his concerns; however, I didn't see value in lengthening my answer to highlight things that seemed evident in the code. And if the asker misread the material available, there could still be a question regardless of how accurate or complete the aforementioned material was. Thinking this might be the case, I felt it better to address his concerns here rather than lengthening my question.